# Can't use ENTER in vim?

Tags: vim

In my vimrc, I use ENTER to expand UltiSnips:

```
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger = '<CR>'
```

But this cause I can't use ENTER in insert mode, how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a solution that works for me based on some tricks described here: [https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/376](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/i%20%20%20%20ssues/376)

```
let g:ulti_expand_or_jump_res = 0
function! ExpandSnippetEx(val)
    let snippet = UltiSnips#ExpandSnippetOrJump()
    if g:ulti_expand_or_jump_res > 0
        return snippet
    else
        return a:val
    endif
endfunction

inoremap <expr> <CR> \<C-R>=ExpandSnippetEx('<C-V><CR>')
```

This attempts to expand the snippet, and if no snippet is found, instead of doing nothing, it inserts an ENTER.

Comment: I already change to use tab for expand. Now, it work nice for me. Thank you any way.